# How do I unlock Mrs. Punkd?

Tags: achievements, killing-floor

There's a new Killing Floor event happening with new weapons and maps and game modes and all that jazz. There's also one intriguing new achievement — unlocking it gives you a permanent free skin.

> **Mrs. Punkd**
>   *Get 4 of 6 of the 2013 Summer Event in-game level Achievements*, one Standard and one Objective Mode map completion Achievement, plus the Punk'd Achievement to unlock Steampunk Mrs. Foster

The emphasized part is giving me trouble. The rest is fairly obvious (unlock Punk'd, complete KF-Steampark, complete KFO-Steampark).

What even is an "Event in-game level Achievement"? One could assume that it's the achievements that say "[2013 Summer]" in their description, but there's a grand total of 3 of those. Are some of them hidden maybe? What do I have to do?

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe it's "Summer Event", "in-game level" "achievements", but I don't know what those are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the 6 achievements it is referring to are Hide and go Puke, Arcade Gamer, Extended Motion Protector, Guardian Assault Protector, Full Charge, and Golden Crown 3 Note. Those are the 6 achievements unique to the new summer map. Hope that helps.

Comment: [b]one Standard[/b] and one Objective Mode map completion Achievement. If you get all the achievement in Objective Mode you must get 1 in standard Steamland map also.

Comment: Looks like this is probably it. Maybe they just forgot to tag half of them with [Summer 2013]. I now have 5/6 of these and I got Mrs. Punkd when I finished KFO-Steamland. What a ride *that* was.